# Parameter value [vbs@gmail.com] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

UserController.java class
If I remove "required=false" error remains same.

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@RequestParam(value= "email", required = false) String email, @RequestParam(value= "password", required = false) String password, ModelMap modelmap) {
    User user = userrepository.getEmailById(email);
    if(user.getPassword().equals(password))
        return "findFlights";
}
```

UserRepository.java class

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User getEmailById(String email);
}
```

login.jsp

```html
<form action="login" method="post">
<pre>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="login">
${msg}
</pre>
</form>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and reformat your question, ideally adding some description on what you are trying to do and especially the exception's stack trace (you should do this in general when asking about exceptions).

Comment: What does class `User` look like? Probably it has an `id` field which is a `Long`. The finder method on the repository interface is incorrect. You say "getEmail**ById**", Spring Data JPA expects you to pass a value that matches `id` - a `Long`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem doesn't seem to be with your controller implementation. It seems an exception thrown by UserRepository implementation where your DB call expects a long but you are sending string.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at data that you shared there are 2 possible cases

- if your user entity has ID column as string and which can be email in this case then your repository should be

`JpaRepository<User,String>`

- if your user entity has ID column as long, then how are you trying to match string email id with long ID column.